# Ограничение нагрузки на систему

Tags: c++

Добрый день.
В программе есть функция, производящая тяжёлые вычисления. Вся задача разбивается на подзадачи, которые выстраиваются в очередь. Есть рабочие потоки, число которых равно числу ядер в процессоре. Эти потоки читают задания из очереди и производят расчёт. В такой конфигурации нагрузка всегда 100%, надо как-то позволить пользователю ограничивать нагрузку на систему. Первое, что пришло в голову, - это замерять время выполнения одной итерации расчёта в потоке и между итерациями вставлять паузы соответственно необходимому снижению нагрузки, например, если время простоя == времени расчёта, то, наверное, загрузка будет 50% (если интервалы достаточно короткие). Может, кто-то подскажет ещё какие-нибудь идеи?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Настраиваемое решение по std::sleep()? Я к тому, что этой функцией поток добровольно отдает право работы другому на некоторое время.

Comment: @sys_dev, причем достаточно даже спать 0 секунд, перехват работы все равно будет. Но чтобы не жонглировать временем процессора между своими потоками, правильнее, например, понизить приоритеты потоков.

Решение же через sleep, если спать предлагается дольше 0, - костыль, который нельзя использовать, потому что теоретически возможны системы и данные, когда это просто увеличит в сотни раз время работы программы.

Comment: @smallFish: Как бы да, Вы правы. Но решение со Sleep портабельно, хоть и ущербное.

Comment: @sys_dev, теоретически можно узнать количество процессоров в системе (в С++11 это делается через `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`) и запускать на поток/на 2 меньше рабочих потоков. А однопроцессорные, как динозавров, грузить как раньше :)

Comment: Еще можно подумать о [thread CPU affinityъ(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html), т.е. привязке потоков к ядрам.

Comment: +1 к @sys_dev, почему бы не сделать число рабочих потоков на 1-2 меньше, чем число ядер?

Comment: @dzhioev: Видимо, Вы хотели +1 другому участнику. Это первое. Второе: Почему не не нажать на соотв. кнопки?

Comment: Забавно, кто то скопировал мою тему отсюда http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=394385 , непонятно в чём смысл сего действа :)

Comment: Наверное, хочет сравнить компетентность участников.